# Inicio de Sesión y manejo de aplicación MVC

Tags: c#, mvc

tengo una aplicación MVC conectada a una base de datos, pero usé el inicio de sesión que ya viene en la plantilla, alguien sabe dónde queda guardada la información de registro?? Intenté buscar en la carpeta App_Data pero no viene nada.

Comment: LocalDB :) revisa en tu web.config la cadena de conexión

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya lo encontré :) Ahora sólo tengo una pregunta, puedo vincular la Vista de Login para que el controlador ahora se conecte a mi base de datos en vez de esa local??

Comment: de nada bro! claro, se supone que ese webconfig lo modificas para que apunte a la BD que deseas

Comment: Lo que pasa es que ya había hecho que después de iniciar sesión (dependiendo del tipo de rol del usuario) me mostrara u ocultara algunas partes del menú superior de navegación, pero ahora después de iniciar sesión ya no me muestra nada... sólo el nombre del usuario, en dónde puedo controlar a que vista o controlador se va después de la validación de la sesión?

Comment: Percibo que estás iniciando con ASP.net MVC, hace un tiempo hice este workshop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY espero te sea de utilidad :D

Comment: La  verdad si, son  mis primeros pasos con MVC jeje, de hecho ya había logrado crear bien la aplicacion y funcionaba pero la verdad ahora que vuelvo a ejecutarla ya no me realiza lo que deseo. Checaré el workshop, gracias!